# How to disable MAAS temporarily without uninstalling it so that I can run Fuel?

Tags: openstack, juju

I have a lab cluster meant for Openstack testing. I've used it for Ubuntu Openstack using Juju/MAAS, and separately, for Fuel 9.2 running on a VM on the same machine. I have been able to test Fuel and Juju separately after tearing down the stack. I can get MAAS running after shutting down the Fuel VM, but Fuel only works after I uninstall MAAS. I'm guessing it's because of the DHCP services running in Fuel and MAAS that interfere with each other.

I want to be able to disable MAAS without uninstalling it. How can I disable MAAS (without uninstalling it) to allow Fuel to work as intended?

Comment: You can stop mass-dhcp service using "sudo service maas-dhcpd stop"

Comment: I did that and it still says "Booting under MAAS direction" when I boot from PXE